# iOS: Change black color in UIImage to another color

Tags: ios, objective-c, colors, uiimage, image-masking

I have an image with white border and black color filled inside it. I want to just change the black color to another color at runtime. The user will select the color at runtime in HSB format. How can I do that? I tried **CGImageCreateWithMaskingColors** by taking 
*const float colorMasking[4]={255, 255, 255, 255};*
but I am getting a nil **CGImageRef** everytime. Please help.

```
- (UIImage*) maskBlackInImage :(UIImage*) image color:(UIColor*)color
{
    const CGFloat colorMasking[4] = { 222, 255, 222, 255 };
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithMaskingColors(image.CGImage, colorMasking);
    UIImage* imageB = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    return imageB;

}
```

I am attaching the image of bulb - Bulb with Black color filled, white border and transparent background
[image: Bulb with Black color filled, White border and transparent background]

**Update:**

I was able to fill black color with another color after using the code in the accepted answer. But, I could see a little bit of color on white border. The image doesn't look that sharp. Attaching the output:

[image: Output - black filled with color]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create a category of `UIImage` class and add the following method

```
- (UIImage *)imageTintedWithColor:(UIColor *)color
{
     UIImage *image;
     if (color) {
        // Construct new image the same size as this one.
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions([self size], NO, 0.0); // 0.0 for scale means "scale for device's main screen".
        CGRect rect = CGRectZero;
        rect.size = [self size];

        // tint the image
        [self drawInRect:rect];
        [color set];
        UIRectFillUsingBlendMode(rect, kCGBlendModeScreen);

        // restore alpha channel
        [self drawInRect:rect blendMode:kCGBlendModeDestinationIn alpha:1.0f];

        image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    }
    return image;
}
```

Comment: This code is changing the color of my white border only. The black fill remains as it is. I just want to change the black fill to other color.

Comment: Recreate your image may be there is some problem. You can open it in preview and resave it.

Comment: That blend mode is the wrong one. Try changing kCGBlendModeMultiply to kCGBlendModeScreen. I think that will do it.

Comment: Worked.. Changed the Blend Mode. Thanks @KristianFox :)

Comment: @abhishekkharwar - I will change the Blend mode in your code and accept the answer

Comment: I can still see a little color outside my white border also. Is there a way to get rid of that also?

Comment: Thanks @Pria, Can you please attach a screenshot hows is it looking?

Comment: @abhishekkharwar - Have added the screenshot in the question. Plz check.

Comment: Is it possible to allow `color` be a colour with alpha that's not 1?

Comment: @LiauJianJie Yes that's possible try this   
    [[UIColor greenColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5f];

Comment: @abhishekkharwar i meant to say that is there a way to modify your snippet so that the black fill can be replaced by a translucent colour?

Comment: @LiauJianJie not sure did you try to change alpha value in  [self drawInRect:rect blendMode:kCGBlendModeDestinationIn alpha:1.0f]; ?

Comment: @abhishekkharwar yea i did, it just changes the alpha of the entire drawing.